# Spring/Mule schema issue

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, mule

I am experiencing the following exception when launching my mule application:

```
SEVERE: Line 6 in XML document from mule-spring-config.xml is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 41; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 6 in XML document from mule-spring-config.xml is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 41; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:97)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.createMuleContext(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:169)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.initialize(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:98)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.contextInitialized(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The following XML is the start of my mule xml configuration file. The schema for spring beans is obviously specified. What is even worst is that the exact same header works for another similar application. Does anyone have a clue what could be the problem here?

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd  
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd  
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd  
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/current/mule-jersey.xsd
    http://jersey.apache.org/core http://jersey.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">

<endpoint name="REST" address="http://localhost:8082/system" />

<!-- Otds connector -->
<spring:bean id="tokenProvider"
    class="com.is.TokenProvider">
    <spring:property name="location"
        value="http://sampleLocation.com" />
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="credentialStoreClient"
    class="com.is.CredentialStoreClient">
    <!-- Integration services protocol -->
    <spring:constructor-arg index="0"
        type="java.lang.String" value="http" />
    <!-- Integration services host -->
    <spring:constructor-arg index="1"
        type="java.lang.String" value="sample.com" />
    <!-- Integration services port -->
    <spring:constructor-arg index="2"
        type="java.lang.String" value="8080" />
    <!-- Integration services context -->
    <spring:constructor-arg index="3"
        type="java.lang.String" value="/server" />
</spring:bean>

<!-- Authentication provider web service class -->
<spring:bean id="authenticationProvider"
    class="com.api.system.AuthenticationProvider">
    <spring:property name="tokenProvider"
        ref="tokenProvider" />
    <spring:property name="credentialStoreClient" ref="credentialStoreClient" />
</spring:bean>

<flow name="API">
    <inbound-endpoint ref="REST" />
    <jersey:resources>
        <component class="com.api.system.VersionSender" />
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="authenticationProvider" />
        </component>
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
</mule>
```

Maybe this will help it was all working before I changed the package name of the VersionSender and Authentication provider classes from admin to system!

**EDIT**

Web.xml the api-config.xml is the mule configuration file above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.mule.config</param-name>
        <param-value>api-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- To use a Mule XML configuration file use this context listener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you show a little more of your configuration? How is the `beans` XML element configured?

Comment: @DavidDossot I have added my entire configuration file. I scrambled it slightly but the main is there.

Comment: Mmmh the exception complains about a `beans` element in `mule-spring-config.xml` but I don't see any in the above configuration. Are we looking at the right things here?

Comment: Thats the thing mule-spring-config.xml does not exist!! Plus my projects do not have any mention to this file. I am trouble as to why this non-existent file is in error.

Comment: Why does Mule try to load it? Is `mule-spring-config.xml` referenced in `mule-deploy.properties` by any chance?

Comment: I am deploying embedding through tomcat and referencing mule configs through the web.xml file of the webapp which I have added to my question as an edit. Sorry for adding information piece by piece but I am not an expert on this yet.

Comment: @DavidDossot The only place where I can actually find references to the mule-spring-config.xml is inside the mule-module-spring-config-3.3.0.jar file which is packaged automatically by Maven.

Comment: OK, I then suspect a dependency issue. Do you use Maven to build your web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the dependencies that get embedded in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your web application: the versions of the Spring JARs must all be `3.1.1.RELEASE` for Mule 3.3.0. Also ensure that you are actually embedding the Spring Beans JAR itself.

Comment: I will look into that. Currently I do not have any explicit dependency to spring all the JAR packaged into the `lib` folder come as a dependency of another JAR and they are all 2.5.6.SEC2

Comment: I have compared the spring dependencies of another project similar to this that is working and you are right the dependencies are all to spring 3.1.1.RELEASE I just need to figure why they changed. Thanks